# Systemd unit file - set environment variable value based on conditional?

Tags: systemd, environment-variables

I was wondering if it's possible to set an environment variables value based off of a conditional inside the systemd unit file, specifically a service file.

Ex:

```
Environment=if (condition) { SOME_VAR=1} else { SOME_VAR=2}
ExecStart=/some/file $SOME_VAR
```

I've tried via bash like so:

```
Environment=/bin/bash -c "if [[condition]]; then SOME_VAR=1; else SOME_VAR=2; fi"
```

But this doesn't work.

So I don't know how to go about this.

Comment: Call bash in `ExecStart`. To avoid quoting difficulties, you should probably put it in a script.

Comment: What kind of *condition* is it? Is it a systemd specific one, is it checked by running a command?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - It's a bash command that checks memory of system.

Answer (score -1):

What if...

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "if [[condition]]; then export SOME_VAR=1; else export SOME_VAR=2; fi"
ExecStart=/some/file $SOME_VAR
```

I'm not sure, that is really working, just dumb guess

Comment: That can't work: it only sets environment variables in the bash process. `ExecStartPre` and `ExecStart` run independent processes, so setting an environment variable in one does not influence the other.